# mod_rewrite help in localhost

Tags: mod-rewrite, xampp, localhost

I have a web site local with xampp, and i want to transform this url `localhost/mysite/frontend/article.php?article_id=something` to `localhost/mysite/frontend/article_id/something`.I use this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ article.php?article_id=$1 [L]
```

but is not right .Could someone help with the right.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for http: //localhost/mysite/frontend/article_id/something if .htaccess is in mysite directory and something is ignored

```
RewriteRule ^frontend/([^/]+)/ /mysite/frontend/article.php?article_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: .htaccess is to frontend directory, this rule didn t work with ^frontend.

Comment: if .htaccess is in frontend directory, use RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ /mysite/frontend/article.php?article_id=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/frontend/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(/(.*?))?/?$ article.php?$1=$3 [L]
```